# Identification of beetle: black with orange stripe and 2 orange dots

Tags: species-identification

I found the following beetle in a wooded area in Essen, Belgium. Does anybody know what species it is? Thanks in advance.

[image: Black beetle with orange stripe and 2 orange dots]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks very much like *Nicrophorus investigator* https://www.pinterest.com/pin/815362707508687290/